# Can some one explain if condition in this logic ie HaspMap Internal Implementation of PutMethod

Tags: java

I didnt understand the If condition ie **if(current.key.equals(newKey))** in this logic and why we need this if condition..

```
public void put(K newKey, V data){
       if(newKey==null)
           return;    //does not allow to store null.

       //calculate hash of key.
       int hash=hash(newKey);
       //create new entry.
       Entry<K,V> newEntry = new Entry<K,V>(newKey, data, null);

       //if table location does not contain any entry, store entry there.
        if(table[hash] == null){
         table[hash] = newEntry;
        }else{
           Entry<K,V> previous = null;
           Entry<K,V> current = table[hash];

           while(current != null){ //we have reached last entry of bucket.
           if(current.key.equals(newKey)){           
               if(previous==null){  //node has to be insert on first of bucket.
                     newEntry.next=current.next;
                     table[hash]=newEntry;
                     return;
               }
               else{
                   newEntry.next=current.next;
                   previous.next=newEntry;
                   return;
               }
           }
           previous=current;
             current = current.next;
         }
         previous.next = newEntry;
        }
    }
```

Can someone explians me what happens if we didnt put that if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hashmap is implemented as a series of buckets corresponding to a range of hashCode values. Each bucket is a linked-list.

In order to put a key-value pair, it is necessary to find it in the bucket if it exists first. In order to do this, the condition `if(current.key.equals(newKey))` is used in a while loop to iterate through the linked-list in the bucket to find the key-value pair if it already exists:

For example:

```
Bucket 0-99: [foo, hashcode 24 -> bar] --> [baz, hashcode 17 -> quux]
Bucket 100-199: [blah, hashcode 114 -> yadayada]
```

In order to `put(baz, quux2)`, `baz` is first hashed, here with an example of hashcode 17. Then, the map searches through the bucket 0-99 by iteration. It is a linked-list, and once it finds an entry with a matching key it will update it:

```
Bucket 0-99: [foo, hashcode 24 -> bar] --> [baz, hashcode 17 -> quux2]
Bucket 100-199: [blah, hashcode 114 -> yadayada]
```

If it cannot find the key in the appropriate bucket, it will simply add it to that bucket.

However, a simple comparison of `current.key.hashCode()==newKey.hashCode()` is not valid, since there may be hashcode collisions. The hashcode is only used to select a bucket, and due to this reason, poor hashcodes only cause a performance loss, rather than data corruption. For example, an exceedingly poor hashcode that always returns `1` will not corrupt the map, but rather will simply cause its performance to degenerate to `O(1)` as all operations are just linked list lookups, insertions, or updates:

```
Bucket 0-99: [foo, hashcode 1 -> bar] --> [baz, hashcode 1 -> quux2] --> [blah, hashcode 114 -> yadayada]
```

Comment: Entry<K,V> current = table[hash];
lets say
Entry<K,V> current = table[5]; and this bucket(Linkedlist bucket contains 5 nodes with it);
then
while(current != null){ //we have reached last entry of bucket.
if(current.key.equals(newKey)){}

we should compare the first element and so till 5 the ele then if con should be like this right 
if(current[i].key.equals(newKey)) {}
but not on the reference of bucket itself..is nt it???

Comment: @user1742919 No. `table` is a table of independent linked lists.

Comment: oh thanks a lot..ur technically too strong..i aprreciate,,thxs for clarification

Comment: @user1742919 If this answer helped, please mark the checkmark at left to specify that it solved your question.